# Selenium WebDriver - KeyPress and Click at the same time C#

Tags: selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

How can I do two action in selenium WebDriver 2 at the same time ?
I need to press and keep CTRL and click on link. I would like to see some solution in C#.

This is not working.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(_driver);
builder.SendKeys(Keys.Control).Click(link).KeyUp(Keys.Control);
IAction multiple = builder.Build();
multiple.Perform();
```

Thank very much for answers

Comment: when I use KeyDown it is not working too

Comment: can you do Ctrl + Enter Key ?  (Enter to simulate click)

Comment: I think Ctrl + Space is for multiselect

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the return value of your builder. Try:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(_driver);
builder = builder.KeyDown(Keys.Control).Click(link).KeyUp(Keys.Control);
IAction multiple = builder.Build();
multiple.Perform();
```

or even an equivalent shorthand of this:

```
new Actions(_driver)
    .KeyDown(Keys.Control)
    .Click(link)
    .KeyUp(Keys.Control)
    .Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the `Actions` to work, you can bail out and invoke javascript (or jQuery, as in my example here), to invoke the *Ctrl-Click*.

Example html fragment (that you're trying to automate the testing of)...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function myClick(e) {if(e.ctrlKey) {alert('ctrl+click');}}
</script>
```

...

```
<img id='myElement' onclick='myClick();' src='abc.gif' />
```

Example c# call:

```
public void ExecuteJs(string javascript)
{
    var js = Browser.WebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    if (js != null) js.ExecuteScript(javascript);
}

public void CtrlClickElement(string elementId)
{
    var script = string.Format("var e=jQuery.Event('click');e.ctrlKey=true;$('#{0}').trigger(e);", elementId);
    ExecuteJs(script);
}
```

...

```
CtrlClickElement("myElement");
```

Reference:

- Related [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6817) on the Selenium Google Code site.
- [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)